# Delete Entity Value Using wit.ai API

Tags: wit.ai

I can't seem to get this request to work:
https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526#delete--entities-:entity-id-values-link

I have setup a "movie" entity with a value of "Chappie", and tried this request (using my bot's token):
$ curl -XDELETE 'https://api.wit.ai/entities/movie/values/Chappie' -H 'Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN'

It returns a 200 response, but "Chappie" is not being remove from my list of "movie" entity values. Has anyone else encountered an issue with this call recently? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the right call. We have a bug on this endpoint, thanks for reporting

**10/05/2016 EDIT: we just pushed a fix. thanks for your patience**